# Indefinite integral with trigonometric functions under square root

Tags: indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Consider indefinite integral:

$I = \int \mathrm{d}x \sqrt{2+\cos(x)+\cos(2x)}$

I was expecting simple result in terms of elliptic function. Unfortuntely, Mathematica spits out very ugly thing.

Can anyone give route for tidier expression?

Comment: Why were you expecting a simple result out of this? It is a complicated integral. What are you supposed to evaluate this for?

Comment: Yes, it's going to look a bit messy in the end. *Mathematica* is not too good at elliptic integrals (something I've griped about many times). After making the substitution $u=\cos x$, you can put your integral into a form where [formula 259.03 of Byrd and Friedman](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0_3) applies.

Comment: this leads to an elliptic integral and this looks very ugly